# Does Salesforce-to-Salesforce use API calls?

Tags: api, integration, limits, salesforce-to-salesforce

Easy question.

I have searched quite a bit, but could not find it: does the Salesforce-to-Salesforce functionality use API calls?

Comment: Do you have it turned on and active already? If so, you could check the "API Usage last 7 days" report. I suspect it doesn't count as only SOAP and REST API calls contribute. [Source](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it uses API calls. Here is the offical salesforce knowledge article about it:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000269202&language=en_US&type=1